# javascript determine what browser is being used on iPhone devices

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

This is the code I'm using to determine what browser user is using on iphone.

```
var browser = (function (agent) {
        switch (true) {
            case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "MS Edge (EdgeHtml)";
            case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1: return "MS Edge Chromium";
            case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "opera";
            case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "chrome";
            case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "Internet Explorer";
            case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "firefox";
            case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "safari";
            default: return "other";
        }
    })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

However, [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/184283/why-third-party-browsers-will-always-be-inferior-to-safari-on-iphone-and-ipad/) it states that all browsers must use safari user agent so the code above will return safari even when using chrome on iphone. Is there a way to determine if chrome is being used in iPhone?

Comment: Browser detection is often quite useless... What are you trying to do based on this information?

Comment: @Cerbrus, we have some features which is not compatible with chrome on Ios. So we are trying to find ways to detect the mobile device (which we can) and the browser (not sure if this is possible) to disable that feature.

Comment: Often feature detection is more reliable. Is there a way you can test for support of said feature, instead of checking the browser? (A function that is unavailable, or that breaks on that specific browser?)